# Why cant I initialize the Webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

im just starting out with android studio,
i have imported WebKit but those imports are grayed.
and i cant initialize the webview "private WebView webview" shows errors
how to do it correctly?
[image]

```
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.app.Activity
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private WebView webview
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO . I know you are doing android programming for first time . You have to first learn kotlin and then  do android programming. For more info go through this. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: In kotlin define variable as follow::::  private val webView:WebView? = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using kotlin instead of java that was the issue (beginner mistake lol)

my issue was that i couldn't initialize the webview on my code. but later i figured i was using kotlin as the programming language instead of using java (since syntax is different in java and kotlin) that was the issue. starting a new project with java solved the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).